# Let $A$ be an $m × n$ matrix. Show that $I_mA = A.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation

Let $A$ be an $m × n$ matrix. We define the Kronecker delta $δ_{ij}$ by $δ_{ij} = 1$ if $i = j$ and $δ_{ij} = 0$ if $i\neq j.$ The $n × n$ identity matrix $I_n$ is defined by $(I_n)_{ij} = δ_{ij}.$ Show that $I_mA = A.$

The solution given is as follows:

> We have, $(I_mA)_{ij} =\sum_{k=1}^m (I_m)_{ik}A_{kj}=\sum_{k=1}^m (\delta)_{ik}A_{kj}=A_{ij}.$

However, I don't get how is the equality $\sum_{k=1}^m (\delta)_{ik}A_{kj}=A_{ij}$ valid? This part of the proof does not seem to make any sense to me.

Comment: $\delta_{ik}A_{kj} = 0$ if $k \neq i$ and $\delta_{ik}A_{kj} = A_{kj} = A_{ij}$ if $k = i$

Comment: $\delta_{ik}=1$ only for $\color{red}{k=i}$. So the only term that will be non-zero is $\delta_{i\color{red}{i}}A_{\color{red}{i}j}=A_{ij}$.